# Cannot start json-server with forever on ubuntu

Tags: json, forever, json-server

I am using below command to start json-server forever on my ubuntu:

```
forever start /usr/local/bin/json-server --watch db.json --port 3001
```

But as I list all processes using `forever list`, I see that the process is stopped. I have also tried to set `--host` flag by putting my private instance ip, but that is also not working. Can you help me to start the `json-server` correctly?

Below are the logs:

```
error: Script restart attempt #1

  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Oops, db.json doesn't seem to exist
  Creating db.json with some default data

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'db.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:454:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1247:35)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/utils/load.js:44:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/utils/load.js:38:10)
    at start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/run.js:112:12)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/run.js:149:3)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/index.js:86:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json-server/lib/cli/bin.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: 'db.json'
}
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

i can confirm that I am running the command in the same folder as that of `db.json`.

I also get below warning:

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: /usr/local/bin/json-server
```

I have some more logs:

```
Cannot bind to the port 3002. Please specify another port number either through --port argument or through the json-server.json configuration file
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

I have tried using other ports as well but that is also not working.

Comment: What is the error you see in logs? Need some more information. what do you see when you run this command - `ps aux | grep json-server` ?

Comment: Actually the problem isn't with ec2. I have tried it on my local machine as well. It is not working there as well.

Comment: Oh.. I have checked logs. It says Error: EACCESS: permission denied, open 'db.json'

Comment: That means you should solve the permission error first. Try running it with sudo once, however that isn't recommended to run with sudo, but for testing it should be ok.

Comment: It is not working with sudo as well

Comment: What you would run to start the server with forever on your machine?